# Android foreground service slow if device is idle

Tags: android, android-service

I have an android foreground service, called with the notification.
In the service Im just logging every 10 seconds "Tick tack", but the priority of the service is navigate in a webview every X seconds, so Im using new threads and working in the main thread too.

If I have the app connected to the usb the logs seems ok, the "tick tack" is called every 10 seconds, same if the mobile is unlocked and Im wathing the logs on the app.

But when I disconnect the usb, or I lock the device this is what is happening:

```
2018-11-14 12:11:53.115 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:12:18.704 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:15:42.572 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:17:30.942 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:17:53.534 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:18:27.118 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:18:37.118 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:18:47.118 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:18:57.121 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:19:25.208 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
2018-11-14 12:19:48.294 12596-12596/? I/Service: tick tack
```

What is the limit of foreground services? Can I do hard foreground work even the device is idle?

Comment: What are you using as a timer?

Comment: Please describe your usecase and how you start the service and what loops the "tick tack".

Comment: @peceps Im starting the service from a push notification, with context.startForegroundService, in the onCreate of the servie I send the notification, the usecase is to report the status of some foreground process, but isnt working

Comment: @PPartisan is a countDownTimer, but the service does more things, but seems that it isnt working as expected

Comment: Could be those Android 8 and 9 restrictions on service... https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: @PabloCegarra - May be worth trying a couple of different strategies for your timer, i.e. a `ScheduledExecutorService`. It's possible this comes as a result of battery optimisation changes in Oreo that take effect when your device is off-charge, but I'd expect those to only kick in after a significant (several minutes) period on battery.

Comment: @PPartisan Im just logging to ensure me that the service is not calling correctly, The purpose of my service is to navigate in background from X websites every X seconds, but the service only works nice connected to the usb, or using the mobile

Comment: @PabloCegarra - My comment remains the same, but you may need to consider an alternate strategy. For instance, if the websites are in the background, then why is it important you navigate between them every X seconds, as the results aren't even visible? Couldn't you just determine what website should be loaded when they come back into the foreground, and do it then? That would be far more efficient and kind to a user's battery life.

Comment: The battery life is not a priority in this project, Is important to simulate correctly a real user navigation in websites. This is why Im keeping all the time a foreground service and Im not using background jobs, the question is... Is it possible? Or the foreground services has a limit too? Im going to try the log with ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: A wake lock is most likely the solution to this problem. If that's not working, that could be because of [deep doze](https://developer.zebra.com/community/home/blog/2017/05/04/keeping-your-application-running-when-the-device-wants-to-sleep), or your wake lock was finalize()'d unexpectedly due to an incorrect scope.

Comment: @PabloCegarra some of the manufacturers who customize native os like (oppo, vivo, xiaomi, Samsung) they have a clear option so when service stops automatically even we start the service at foreground service, I'm too looking for this solution many ppl says if we start foreground service it will work fine but it not like that (8.0) devices restrict the service automatically when the device unlock, did you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: @RamSuthakar Im trying with the permission REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS + wifilock + wakelock but my service sometimes doesnt have internet connection

Comment: @PabloCegarra tried android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/> this one in my case but it will stop automatically within 10 mins :(

Answer (score 1):

I have made this library the other day for something similar [service in background and foreground](https://github.com/HossamScott/Background_service)

And its working absolutely fine with no problems.

The reason I choose to run it with `AlarmManager` is that the `AlarmManager` is a great candidate for scheduling if an application needs to perform a local event + allows an application to schedule tasks that may need to run or repeat beyond the scope of its lifecycle. This allows the application to perform some function even after the application process or all of its Android components have been cleaned up by the system.

**UPDATE**

Call this method to start the service

```
 public void call(int Value_in_seconds) {
        if (Value_in_seconds == (int) Value_in_seconds) {
            // Number is integer
            Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + Value_in_seconds * 1000;
            // create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers, here
            // ServiceReciever in the Intent, the onRecieve() method of this class will execute when
            // alarm triggers
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, ServiceReciever.class);
            // create the object
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            //set the alarm for particular time
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,  context.getString(R.string.intValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Create `ServiceReciever`  Class

```
public class ServiceReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //call the method here

    }
}
```

inside your `manifest`

```
<application>
<receiver android:name="hossamscott.com.github.backgroundservice.ServiceReciever" android:process=":ff" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
</receiver>

<service android:name="hossamscott.com.github.backgroundservice.BackgroundTask"/>

</application>
```

And thats should be it, tho if you like to run it in `Thread` 
Than you can add the next lines

```
public class BackgroundTask extends Service {

    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;
    private Thread backgroundThread;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context = this;
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something here
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do your logic here
                }
            });
            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

And to call this `class` edit `ServiceReciever` to be like this

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //call the method here
        Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundTask.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }
```

Comment: I need to keep the same service up almost for 20 o 30 minutes, without lossing the state of the webview, so I think the problem is not to start with the alarm manager or not, the real problem is to stay all this time doing a lot of job consuming cpu and ram

Comment: for me when i was running tests with short times it never failed even when the app was killed , you can try it and give me feedback i will be able to edit it for you

Comment: this library is working fine, but only when the app is in foreground, removing the app the broadcast/service is going to be "killed"

Comment: I will update my answer with code to run it even in the background

Comment: Ops! If I call a service then I have the same problem, android services stops my code when the device is idle

Comment: maybe the device you are testing on have battery saver on? in that case, you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478954/how-can-i-prevent-galaxy-s3-from-stopping-my-app-when-turning-idle

Comment: Yes like all the android >=8, I tried the partial wake lock and the result is the same

Comment: i think i have found you solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42057958/how-to-keep-application-awake-in-background "raise priority"

Comment: This is not my problem, Im calling startForeground(id, notification) in my service

Comment: @HossamHassan is that possible to run the foreground service more than 1 hour when the app in background mode? did you checked that one in 8.0 devices i have chekced that one but service only runs 5 mins

Comment: I have tested it up to 9.0 and its working fine, i even let the service run in background whole night and it doesnt stop, as long as the app is not killed and its in the background, Make sure to Recall the service after it expire( for example inside your receive method set the timer again if u want it to run multi times)

Comment: @HossamHassan I have tried your sample GitHub but it doesn't work more than 10 mins it will be stopped automatically here is my image link https://i.imgur.com/Ee51n9n.png