# Using internet in background service when android phone is in the sleep

Tags: android, android-service

I defined a service and its work perfectly when the app is in the foreground, but when I close app and phone goes to sleep, the service doesn't work with the internet and I get **timeout error**. my wifi is connected to the internet when the phone is in sleep.
what can I do?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

Comment: Check out my answer here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299557/android-foreground-service-slow-if-device-is-idle/53343474#53343474

Answer (score 0):

You better make service and use broadcast receiver in it and listen broadcaster on every state change of internet connectivity.